# which file or directory is not able to read?

Tags: docker, jenkins

in while i'm trying to build an image im getting following error.
In this image i need to download jenkins, run jenkins in background and then download jenkins-cli, then i have to give my input to cli.

```
       FROM ubuntu:14.04

    RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y  software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -f -y oracle-java9-installer && \
    apt install -y default-jre curl wget git nano; \
    apt-get clean


# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get -y update  && \
    apt-get -yqq --no-install-recommends install git bzip2 curl unzip && \
    apt-get update

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

# copy jenkins war file to the container
ADD http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.107.1/jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
RUN chmod 644 /opt/jenkins.war
ENV JENKINS_HOME /jenkins

# configure the container to run jenkins, mapping container port 8080 to that host port
ENTRYPOINT ["nohup","java", "-jar", "/opt/jenkins.war"]
RUN mkdir /jenkins/
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /jenkins

#jenkins-cli installation
RUN mkdir -p /jcli
RUN chmod 644 /jcli
RUN curl --insecure -OL http://192.168.99.100:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar \
   --output /jcli/jenkins-cli.jar
VOLUME /ssh
ENV JENKINS_URL "http://192.168.99.100:8080"
ENV PRIVATE_KEY "C:\Users\himn\.ssh/id_rsa"
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/jcli/jenkins-cli.jar","-noCertificateCheck","-noKeyAuth"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

[image: Here is the Error]

[image: Updated error]

[image: after adding / before opt]
[image: Build Succuss]

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is jenkins-cli downloading
2. which directory its unable to locate
3. do i need to run jenkins in background to download jenkins-cli aand 
   work and How to do it?
4. and solutions for it

Thank u in advance

**last few lines of my Dockerfile**

```
# copy jenkins war file to the container
ADD http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.107.1/jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
RUN chmod 644 /opt/jenkins.war
ENV JENKINS_HOME /jenkins

# configure the container to run jenkins, mapping container port 8080 to that host port
ENTRYPOINT ["nohup","java", "-jar", "/opt/jenkins.war"]
RUN mkdir /jenkins/
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /jenkins

#jenkins-cli installation
RUN mkdir -p /jcli
RUN chmod 644 /jcli
RUN curl --insecure -OL http://192.168.99.100:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar \
   --output /jcli/jenkins-cli.jar
VOLUME /ssh
ENV JENKINS_URL "http://192.168.99.100:8080"
ENV PRIVATE_KEY "C:\Users\himn\.ssh/id_rsa"
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/jcli/jenkins-cli.jar","-noCertificateCheck","-noKeyAuth"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

Comment: Can you please share your Dockerfile after considering  @vivekyad4v answer?

Comment: its updated in my Question @fly2matrix

Comment: This file is download correctly. and it must be available at /opt/tmp/jenkin-cli.jar

Comment: Step-20, 21 and 22 are not required..
So where-ever you need to refer to the jenkin-cli.jar you the absolute path (/opt/tmp/jenkin-cli.jar)

Downloaded file is already in the image, so no need to perform copy (COPY instruction is to transfer files from host-machine to docker-container).

Comment: It would be better if you share your Dockerfile on github... I can help you over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try after updating your Dockfile entrypoint as

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/opt/tmp/jenkin-cli.jar","-noCertificateCheck","-noKeyAuth"]
```

and also remove following lines:

```
RUN chmod 644 jenkins-cli.jar
WORKDIR /opt/tmp/jenkins-cli
COPY opt/tmp/jenkins-cli.jar ./jenkins-cli
```

Comment: its build successfully,Now can anyone tel how it need to be run, i mean how can i get that cli to run in my container?? @fly2matrix

Comment: @vivekyad4v I have shared the scree shot of build succuss

Comment: Now when you start your container - your ENTRYPOINT will take care of starting it , #> docker run <docker-image-name>

Comment: $ docker run 584acd244722
Error: Unable to access jarfile /jcli/jenkins-cli.jar
(i have changed the path of jenkins-cli compared to code in question @fly2matrix

Comment: Seems like missing a root in the beginning of the path../opt/tmp/jenkin-cli.jar

Comment: u mean do i need to add "." before all /opt ? @fly2matrix

Comment: its updated in Question. **/opt/tmp/ is edited to /jcli**

Comment: coz it was locating to my tmp files in other folders @fly2matrix

Comment: you can not have more than one entry point ...One suggestion in case you have lots of RUN statements then you can concat them using  && \

Comment: ENTRYPOINT ["nohup","java","-jar","/opt/jenkins.war" && "/jcli/jenkins-cli.jar","-noCertificateCheck","-noKeyAuth"]
**will this work?** @fly2matrix

Comment: no it will not as docker is going to concat all these argument together to make a complete command.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a typo error. In your curl command i.e step 19/27, `--output` is `/opt/tmp/jenkin-cli.jar` it needs to be `/opt/tmp/jenkins-cli.jar`.

Error states that it is unable to locate the file `/opt/tmp/jenkins-cli.jar` because you created the file with name `jenkin-cli.jar` & not `jenkins-cli.jar`.

Now the 2nd mistake is you are missing `/` before `opt` and moreover, 
 `COPY` works from host to container & not within the container. In that case, you don't need to download the CLI to create a container and image.

Comment: thank u and i accept your correction,but still its same error when i try to copy that file, i have updated screen shot of new error, you can check in my question @vivekyad4v

Comment: Updated my asnwer. This time you missed a `/` before `opt` and the directory goes unrecognizable. It happens, np.

Comment: Share new screenshot please.

Comment: Step-20, 21 and 22 are not required.. So where-ever you need to refer to the jenkin-cli.jar use the absolute path (/opt/tmp/jenkin-cli.jar) ....Downloaded file is already in the image, so no need to perform copy (COPY instruction is to transfer files from host-machine to docker-container).

Comment: Exactly. COPY works from host to container & not within the container. In that case, you don't need to download the CLI to create a container and image.